# Does a linkedList takes longer to be sorted?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

A question just poped into my mind, since the time complexity of `get(index)` method of a linkedList are not O(1), but are O(N), so, does it affect the time complexity of sorting? For example, the below code (bubble sort):

```
public static void bubbleSort(int arr[])
{
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
}
```

When I perform the bubble sort, I need to get the elements. In any sorting algorithm, you need to get the elements, so... Does it takes an average time complexity of O(n*log(n)*n) when I perform the bubble sort? If it is, when I use `Collections.sort(linkedList)`, is the average time complexity also O(n*log(n)*n)?

Comment: As I recall, The Java List implementation has a backing array. So the get operations are always guaranteed to be O(1). Also, you can implement something similar to it using HashMaps to store indices of nodes in the list.

Comment: `Collections.sort` uses QuickSort or an adapted version of TimSort depending on the list size. For these algorithms, the complexity is O(log(n)) or O(n log(n))

Comment: @Harsh __ArrayList__ has that property, LinkedList does not. No, a get() op on a java list operation is not guaranteed to be O(1) at all.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thanks for the info. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the implementation of the `List.sort` (Java 13)

```
 default void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    Object[] a = this.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator) c);
    ListIterator<E> i = this.listIterator();
    for (Object e : a) {
        i.next();
        i.set((E) e);
    }
}
```

As you can see doesn't matter what list implementation you want to sort, the performance will be the almost the same.

Now, if we look how the `toArray` is implemented we see the following:

**LinkedList**

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    Object[] result = new Object[size];
    int i = 0;
    for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
        result[i++] = x.item;
    return result;
}
```

**ArrayList**

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
}
```

So, if you want to sort a LinkedList, it will be a little bit slower than ArrayList but not to much.

Answer (score 2):

For "when you perform the bubble sort," it depends on how you implement bubble sort.  Bubble sort in particular *can* take O(n^2) -- no worse than usual -- with a linked list, since it always addresses elements right next to each other.  A naive implementation would take O(n^3) as you describe, though.

From the Javadoc of `Collections.sort`:

> This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array. This avoids the n<sup>2</sup> log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in place.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it takes an average time complexity of O(n*log(n)*n) when I perform the bubble sort?

You're operating under a misconception there. Bubble sort is `O(n^2)`. It's not an efficient sorting algorithm.

LinkedList is mostly useless; the situations where it will outperform arraylist are effectively non-existent (you'd think O(1) insertion anywhere is useful, but you don't actually get that unless you have a listIterator, and the downsides, performance-wise, are vastly worse than algorithmic complexity suggests due to the way it interacts with on-die caches (namely: very very badly).

As the answer by Octavian already highlights, the default impl of sorting for all lists (and LinkedList does not bother to change this behaviour, but it could) is to just make a complete copy into something with O(1) get access, sort there, and then copy it all back in. Algorithmically, that means it's just adding `O(n)` factors, which is irrelevant (sorting as it at least `O(n log n)` after all.

Remember, algorithmic complexity just tells you the behaviour of its performance once you give it large enough inputs relative to other large inputs. one `O(n^2)` algorithm can be a thousand times faster than another.

Sorting a LinkedList like this is... not great. Much slower than an ArrayList, even if not in terms of `O(n)`.